# Merge two JSON documents together

Tags: json, ansible, jq, idempotent

I am trying append some JSON to existing `~/.docker/config.json` document using Ansible.

Document 1 `~/.docker/config.json`

```
{
        "auths": {
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                        "auth": "supercalifragilistic"
                }
        },
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.03.0-ce (windows)"
        }
}
```

Document 2 `credHelper.json`

```
{
    "credHelpers": {
        "111111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" : "ecr-login"
    }
}
```

I have been spending some time with `jq` but cannot get it to work. This is the result of jq.

`jq -s '.' credHelpers.json config.json`

```
[
  {
    "credHelpers": {
      "111111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
    }
  },
  {
    "auths": {
      "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
        "auth": "supercalifragilistic"
      }
    },
    "HttpHeaders": {
      "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.03.0-ce (windows)"
    }
  }
]
```

What I want is this:

```
{
    "auths": {
            "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                    "auth": "supercalifragilistic"
            }
    },
    "HttpHeaders": {
            "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.03.0-ce (windows)"
    },
    "credHelpers": {
            "111111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
    }
}
```

I Hope I can make this idempotent, too, so the merging/joining doesn't keep happening recursively each time playbook is run.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the code that you're looking for?

```
    - set_fact:
        doc1: "{{ lookup('file', 'config.json') }}"
        doc2: "{{ lookup('file', 'credHelper.json') }}"
    - debug: msg="{{ doc1 | combine(doc2) }}"



TASK [debug] **********************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "HttpHeaders": {
            "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.03.0-ce (windows)"
        }, 
        "auths": {
            "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
                "auth": "supercalifragilistic"
            }
         }, 
         "credHelpers": {
            "111111111111.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will try this one out, and make a decision soon.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the picture, this is also possible with `jq`, simply `add` two json files:

```
jq -s 'add' credHelpers.json config.json
```

The `add` filter takes as input an array, and produces as output the elements of the array added together, as the `jq` [documentation says](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). In addition you need the `--slurp/-s` command line option, which turns the entire input stream into a large array and runs the filter just once.

Comment: I like `add`. It works. Will try to use Ansible-native solution (fewer dependencies), and then I'll decide the victor.